# MongoDB atlas not working when project is hosted on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, git, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I have hosted a MERN project on Heroku. The app is running absolutely fine in localhost. But after production, the Heroku app is not able to connect to MongoDB Atlas[image]. I have whitelisted my IP in Atlas to give access from anywhere and have configured the MONGODB_URI config var in Heroku. But it is still not working. Here, I am attaching the screenshot of the Heroku logs and also the git repo of the project. Can someone help me out?

[Heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Uun.png)

The git repo: https://github.com/Sayak-0512/Remnotes-Remember-all-the-notes.git

**Edit:**
Found the problem. Actually process.env.MONGO_URI was not being used in the code and I was hardcoding the mongo url string in the code. On adding process.env.MONGO_URI, it worked.

Comment: First you should try connecting from mongo shell using that connection string. It might be possible that you missed something during IP Whitelisting configuration or your connection string itself if incorrect. I was not able to connect using the creds you have printed in logs.

Comment: I have rechecked my credentials and my connection string many times. They are absolutely fine. And moreover the project is working fine in local host with the same connection string and credentials.

Comment: The credentials in the logs are not my atlas credentials. They are the credentials of the login feature of the hosted app.